# Back button with multiple steps and different urls in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, history, popstate

I'm trying to write a js script for my page that:

Starting from Home Page

I click first time on back button and I go on first-url

I click second time on back button and I got on second-url

I click third time on back button and I got on third-url

Is it possibile? 
This is the script that I'm using now, that allows me to go from home page to first-url. 
From first-url I click again the back button and it comes back on home page, and then click again it comes back on first-url and so on.

```
!function () {
    {history.pushState({}, "", "#");
    onpopstate = function (e) {

        location.replace("https://www.first-url.com")
    }
}
}();
```

Any help please to add second-url and third-url?

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
 $(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
     window.location.href = 'https://www.first-url.com';
    });
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.first-url.com') {
 $(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
     window.location.href = 'https://www.second-url.com';
    });
}
```